# Is there any way to skip the tutorial city in SimCity?

Tags: simcity-2013

You're stuck playing through the tutorial city whenever switching regions.  Quitting the tutorial city doesn't skip it, and I'm not seeing anything else.  Have any tricks up your sleeve?

Edit: quitting the city does appear to be working for other people

Comment: I changed server and have to do the tutorial again. Most annoying.

Comment: I was going to say simply quit the tutorial city, as that's what worked for me and my friends, but you say it didn't work. What happened instead?

Comment: I came back to the menu, and the only option was to go back to the tutorial.  Maybe it was a propagation delay

Comment: Nevir, you must click the `first` tutorial popup step when the tutorial starts. If you exit the tutorial before the first it explains how to use the camera, then you will have to run the tutorial again. After that, exiting to the menu will cancel it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To skip the tutorial.

Click the `Getting Started` button on the home screen. The tutorial city will load, and a welcome message popup will show in the lower corner.

You *must* click the `Okay` button to start the tutorial in order to skip it. If you don't start the tutorial, then it won't work.

Once the next popup appears called "CAMERA". Click the *options* button `(...` in the upper right corner, and then click `Exit To Main Menu`.

When you return to the main menu the tutorial will have been cancelled. You can now go and create your first city for that server.

Answer (score 15):

No **you can not skip the tutorial** as this is [how you register on a server](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Miscellaneous-Issues/Tutorial-not-loading/m-p/628232#U628232). **However, you can just exit out of the tutorial after you have started it** and then continue to play on the server. It seems that just getting into the tutorial is enough to do this registration, you do not have to play through it.

Answer (score 3):

Just start tutorial and then go back to the main menu and you'll be able to play normal game.

Answer (score 0):

Start the tutorial and then immediate exit it, you don't need to finish it.

As ESC doesn't work in tutorial, you have to click the Settings icon in the upper right corner of the screen to open the menu.

Also, if the application should accidentally crash, tutorial on that server will not come up again.